# Laravel localization error

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-5.4

I tried to localise the "base theme" (what we get after the make:auth), but I got this error message:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''failed'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'`

Only I changed the Login to @lang('auth.login') (I made a login string in the auth localisation file)

```
'login' => 'Login',
```

Code snippet from the template:

```
@if (Auth::guest())
    <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}"> @lang('auth.login') </a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
@else
    <li class="dropdown">
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't think the error is located in the given code !! in witch file and line the error is occured ? look at the error stack trace

Comment: Where do you have the `'failed'` string ? Is it in your localisation file ? If yes, be sure to put a `,` at the end of the previous line. By looking at the error message, it look like there is no `,`, so it expecting the end of the array, but there is another localization string instead.

Comment: @Garric15 thank you, that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tell you it expecting the end of the array, but there is another string instead. Each values must be separated  by comma.

So put a `,` at the end of the previous line.

From this:

```
[
    'something' => 'Something'
    'failed' => 'Failed',
    ...
];
```

to this:

```
[
    'something' => 'Something',
    'failed' => 'Failed',
    ...
];
```